# Obtaining the index of elements that belong to common group in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have the following data frame,

```
>df
  Label
0 control1
1 control1
2 control2
3 control2
4 control1
```

To get the index of the elements with label control1 and control2, I do the following

```
Index1 <- grep("control1",df[,1])
Index2 <- grep("control2",df[,1])
```

In the above syntax, the labels control1 and control2 are explicity mentioned in the command.

Is there a way to find the labels automatically? The reason is the data frame, df,contents are parsed from different input files.
For instance, I could have another data frame that reads

```
>df2
  Label
0 trol1
1 trol1
2 trol2
3 trol3
4 trol2
```

Is there a way to create a list of unique labels present in the column of df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` to get list of index according to unique `Label`

```
split(1:nrow(df), df$Label)

#$control1
#[1] 1 2 5

#$control2
#[1] 3 4
```

---

With `df2`

```
split(1:nrow(df2), df2$Label)

#$trol1
#[1] 1 2

#$trol2
#[1] 3 5

#$trol3
#[1] 4
```

Comment: In place of `df$Label` I tried `df$colnames(df)[1]` , `Error: attempt to apply non-function` . Could you please suggest how this error can be avoided?

Comment: @Natasha Can you update your expected output? It is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was just trying to use colnames(df)[1] to get the column name of the data frame.  Anyway , thanks a lot. I sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using `unique` and `which` you can do:

```
df <- data.frame(Label = c("trol1", "trol1", "trol2", "trol3", "trol2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
label_idx = list()
for(lbl in unique(df$Label)){
    label_idx[[lbl]] = which(df$Label == lbl)
}
label_idx

$`trol1`
[1] 1 2

$trol2
[1] 3 5

$trol3
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try also

```
lapply(unique(df$Label), function(x) which(df$Label%in% x))

#with df
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

lapply(unique(df2$Label), function(x) which(df2$Label%in% x))
#with df2
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 5

[[3]]
[1] 4
```